# declare spring bean of string type one line

Tags: java, spring

I want to declare a bean of String type in an spring xml context in the shortest way possible. So far this is the shortest way I've found

```
<bean id="bean1" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg type="String" value="someword" />
</bean>
```

However, for readability, I would like to 'stack' multiple of these neatly, kinda like so, and I can't just put all the code on one line because of team standards about line code length:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="java.lang.String">blah blah </bean>
<bean id="bean2" class="java.lang.String">blah blah </bean>
<bean id="bean3" class="java.lang.String">blah blah </bean>
```

Comment: May I know the reason of creating bean(s) of `String` class?

Comment: Going to be referenced in a ton of places throughout the context, so would like be able to maintain it from one location.

Comment: You should create an interface or `final` class and put all these Strings there. You can easily reference it throughout your project.

Comment: Essentially a class of constants and reference it by SpEL? For readability I would still prefer keeping it all in the context file and also I can redeploy the context file separately to the classpath without having to redeploy the whole .jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For readability I would still prefer keeping it all in the context file and also I can redeploy the context file separately to the classpath without having to redeploy the whole .jar

If you want to keep everything in the context file and want to simplify it then you should be using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of `String` beans.

Here is an example,

1. Create a properties file named as `project.properties`.
2. Put all your `Strings` inside that file as `{key=value}` pair. For Example,

   ```
   myStrings.cnst1=FOO
   myStrings.cnst2=BAR
   myStrings.cnst3=FOOBAR
   ```
3. Now, declare a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` inside your context file as follows:

   ```
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">
       <value>project.properties</value>
   </property>
   ```
4. Now, you can easily access the values as follows:

   ```
   @Value("${myStrings.cnst1}")
   private String someString;
   ```

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182625/is-there-a-shorthand-for-creating-a-string-constant-in-spring-context-xml-file) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596235/shortcut-for-injecting-strings-with-spring) for more information.