# spring autowiring of string bean in interceptor fails with NPE

Tags: spring, autowired

Autowiring is failing for a spring handlerInterceptorAdapter.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating   bean with name 'pathInterceptor': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.spring.framework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field:    
private java.lang.String com.mine.spring.interceptors.PathInterceptor.vendor; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/09 23:29:41 |       at    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/09 23:29:41 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1218)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/09 23:29:41 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/09 23:29:41 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/09 23:29:41 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/09 23:29:41 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/09 23:29:41 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
```

Here is the snipet from the springxml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

...

```
<bean id="vendor" class="java.lang.String" c:_0="MyVendor"/>

<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="com.mine.spring.interceptors.PathInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Here is the snippet from the java class

```
@Component
public class PathInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("vendor")
private String vendor;
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Follow this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36315807/3003337

Answer (score 0):

I think your String bean (heh) syntax is wrong.

```
<bean id="vendor" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="MyVendor"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I do this all the time and it works fine.  You just declare c in the namespace:  xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"

Answer (score 0):

There was some kind of custom autowiring library in my context scan that was messing up the standard autowiring.  I didn't track it down anymore than figuring out the custom library and removing it to allow the autowiring to work properly.